# How do I dynamically set textwidth to suit the current file?

Tags: vim

For a long time I have written prose text files using textwidth:80. I want to start using textwidth:72, for Reasons.

If I just change my .vimrc to use 72, I run into a problem. Either I have to re-wrap any old files I touch (making for extra proofreading and large, semantically useless git commits), or I end up with blocks of 72-column text in files that are otherwise 80-column, which is ugly.

I would like to have vim figure out the appropriate textwidth when I open the file. Something like "make textwidth 72 columns or the maximum common line length in this file, whichever is longer." I include 'common' because I don't want a few overlength lines -- perhaps long URLs -- to affect textwidth.

How do I do this?

Comment: To set the text width when you open a file, you can include an autocommand in your `.vimrc` like this: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.java set textwidth=72`. You can get the max line length of a file with `wc -L`. This doesn't really answer the question, but maybe it helps a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Getting the lengths

You can get a List of the (ascending) lengths of all lines of the current buffer via:

```
let lengths = sort(map(getline(1, '$'), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val)'), 'n')
```

Then, maybe remove the longest 1% to account for any outliers (or apply even more elaborate statistics here), and obtain the maximum of the rest:

```
let max = max(lengths[0: (len(lengths) * 99 / 100)])
```

And use that to detect legacy files which wrap at column 80:

```
let isLegacyWidth = max > 72 && max <= 80
```

#### Setting textwidth

This can be done via `:autocmd`. The most important question here is how to discriminate your "prose text files". If you have a custom filetype (e.g. `text`), you can use

```
autocmd FileType text ...
```

If these are stored in certain location(s):

```
autocmd BufReadPost /path/to/prose/* ...
```

Assuming you've put the above length checks into a `IsLegacyWidth()` function, you can set the local `'textwidth'` value with:

```
let &l:textwidth = (IsLegacyWidth() ? 80 : 72)
```